# How do I give players an enchanted book?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to set a command to give a player an Unbreaking V book (rare item in crate) however I'm not sure how to do it, as the way I normally give enchanted items just gives me a enchanted book with Unbreaking V but it can't be applied to items through an anvil, so I'm assuming it's different for books?

Or, alternatively, is it that it's impossible to give out-of-vanilla-Minecraft enchanted book, as Unbreaking III books would still be sufficient!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Enchanted books store the enchantments that they're going to pass onto other items slightly differently than normal enchantments actually on an item. Otherwise, the enchantments on the book intended for passing on would be usable (set mobs on fire with a fire aspect book, or get more loot with a fortune book).

Rather than the `ench` list, the pass-on enchantments are in a `StoredEnchantments` list, everything else is the same.

**For 1.13+:**

```
/give @p enchanted_book{StoredEnchantments:[{id:"minecraft:unbreaking",lvl:5s}]}
```

**For previous versions:**

```
/give @p enchanted_book 1 0 {StoredEnchantments:[{id:34s,lvl:5s}]}
```

Answer (score 3):

Just because I keep forgetting that 1.13 has changed things up a bit and I keep running across this when I lookup how to enchant a book I wanted to add this.

http://mapmaking.fr/give/

`/give @p minecraft:enchanted_book{StoredEnchantments:[{id:"minecraft:unbreaking",lvl:5}]} 1`

or if you want to use the ID you still can

`/give @p enchanted_book{StoredEnchantments:[{id:34,lvl:5}]} 1`

Answer (score 1):

It's very simple here's the answer

```
/give @p minecraft:enchanted_book 1 0 {StoredEnchantments:[{id:34,lvl:3}]}
```

You can only seem to give yourself enchanted books that exist in the game.

Answer (score 1):

If you want enchanted books try using this:

```
/give <name> minecraft:enchanted_book 1 0 {StoredEnchantments:[{id:16,lvl:3}]}
```

To add more enchantments to the book use

```
/give <name> minecraft:enchanted_book 1 0 {StoredEnchantments:[{id:16,lvl:3},{id:34,lvl:3}]}
```